# Filter based on column value match in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write query that matches the value in a column with the value in another column.

example Column 1 value : Newport
Column 2 Value: Medical Council Newport

I want to use a filter that select the rows where the entire value in column 1 matches with the column 2 partially.

i cant  to use the filter condition based on string match

```
select * from tb1 
where column2 like '%Newport%' -- this doesnt work for me
```

Comment: select * from tb1 where column2 like '%' + column1 + '%' ?

Comment: `like '%Newport%' ` "this doesnt work for me" Why?

Comment: Tim -- because column1 won't always have the value Newport.

Comment: @KathyA.: That's why parameters exist. `LIKE '%' + @Value + '%'`

Comment: @Tim. Absolutely. The OP was saying that using the string literal wouldn't work.

Comment: Is column2 a text field and thats why the like doesn't work? Why can't you use a string match?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_Name 
WHERE Col2 LIKE '%'+ Col1 + '%'
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: @gung I saw it in the queue reviewed it and approved it as it's all that is required to answer this specifc question